# Find domain of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find the domain of function $$f(x,y)=\arccos\frac{x}{x+y}+\sqrt{3-x^2-2x-y^2}.$$
It's easy to see that $-1\leq\frac{x}{x+y}\leq 1$ and $3-x^2-2x-y^2\geq 0$, but I don't know how to combine those two facts to find the actual domain.

Comment: You need $x,y\neq 0$ as well. Notice that $3-x^2-2x-y^2=-(x-1)^2-y^2+4.$

Comment: @Surb Don't you really need $x+y \neq 0$? Note that $x=1,y=-1$ is not in domain since makes a zero denominator.

Comment: @coffeemath: yes of course.

Comment: have you tried drawing a picture to illustrate these inequalities?

Comment: @DavidQuinn It's easy to draw $3-x^2-2x-y^2\geq 0$, but the other inequality is a bit more difficult for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint...
$$\frac{x}{x+y}<1\implies \frac{x}{x+y}-1<0\implies\frac{y}{x+y}>0$$

Then either $\{y>0 \cap x+y>0\} \cup \{y<0 \cap x+y<0\}$

These are two regions you can shade in the $xy$ plane inside the circle you already know about.

Proceed in a similar way with $\frac{x}{x+y}>-1$